# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I create a service EmployeeService and then created action in this service (GetAllEmployee)

```
    public void GetAllEmployee()
    {
        List<EmployeeModel> listEmployees = new List<EmployeeModel>();
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from EmployeesTbl", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                EmployeeModel emp = new EmployeeModel
                {
                    Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]),
                    Name = (rdr["Name"]).ToString(),
                    Gender = (rdr["gender"]).ToString(),
                    Salary = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["salary"])
                };
                listEmployees.Add(emp);

            }
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listEmployees));
    }
}
```

}

and in my js part

```
var myApp = angular
            .module("MyModule", [])
            .config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {

                $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);

            }])
            .controller("serverController", function ($scope, $http) {

                $http.post('EmployeeService.asmx/GetAllEmployee')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        //$scope.emp = defer.resolve(response.data)
                        $scope.emp = response.data;
                    });

            });
```

when I run the project , this appears in the console

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
and here is a screen shoot when I click on the error
[image]
how can I fix it?

Comment: Debug the application and see which line of code crashes.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani I don't see any crashes but the error in the console

Comment: 500 means there is error on server side.
and in your $http.post on JS write failure handler as well.

Comment: @WasifKhan so how can I fix it please ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose your webservice named as **GetAllEmployee**.

In java, we use resources and put annotation to expose webservice/endpoints.
And are you hitting your correct webservice, means it is post Webserivce with url GetAllEmployee?

Have not worked in ASP MVC. cant say how u will do it.